# Cannot resolve symbol in Room database

Tags: java, android, database, roomdb

**I have a problems in MainDao.class:**

- Cannot resolve symbol 'notes_table'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'id'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'notes_table'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'title'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'description'

**How can I fix this?**

My Code:

Class MainDao

```
@Dao
public interface MainDao{
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(Notes notes);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes_table ORDER BY id DESC")
    List<Notes> getAll();

    @Query("Update notes_table SET title = :title, description = :description where id = :id")
    void update(int id, String title, String description);

      @Delete
void delete(Notes notes);}
```

Class RoomDB.java

```
@Database(entities = Notes.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)


   @Dao
    public abstract class RoomDB extends RoomDatabase {
    private static RoomDB database;
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "NoteApp";

    public synchronized static RoomDB getInstance(Context context) {
        if (database == null) {
            database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RoomDB.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return database;
    }

    public abstract MainDao MainDao();
}
```

Class Notes.java

```
    @Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
public class Notes implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    String title = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    String description = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    String date = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this:

```java
@Database(entities = Notes.class ,version = 1,exportSchema = false)
```

to

```java
@Database(entities = {Notes.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
```